# Skype and media player causing windows explorer to crash

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash, skype

When there are 2 or more Skype windows on screen, windows explorer will instantly crash and it will keep crashing after restart as long as there is more than one skype window on the screen. When I leave just one, it works normaly.

One window: (it doesn't need to be the main window)
[image]
Opening another window: (in this case it's the settings but it can be anything, a chat, a call, even a confirmation dialog)

[image]

With media player it is different. It crashes only upon switching from Now playing to Library or vice versa:
[image] [image]. .
It is especially annoying when I plug in a flash drive during music playback and it switches to library automatically.

These 2 programs are the only thing that cause explorer to crash. It works normally with all other programs and never crashes by itself. I've had this problem for years, ever since I installed windows 7, but it was only media player and wasn't such a big deal. I used a very old version of skype which worked, but now I was forced to update and this new version is practically unusable due to this problem.

I use Windows 7 Home 64bit with Classic shell and classic theme. Uninstalling Classic shell and restoring the default theme does not solve the problem. 
sfc /scannow does not solve the problem either.

Comment: Did you check the [event viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) for further details?

Comment: capture a crash dump of the explorer with procdump: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-9-ProcDump

Comment: I am not really used to checking the event viewer. Will have to do it more from now on. :) It shows that a dll called "inject.dll" is crashing every time this happens. The dll belongs to a program called 7 Taskbar Tweaker that makes the taskbar behave like in older versions of Windows. I updated the program to the newest version and the problem is gone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the event viewer, it seems that the problem was caused by 7 Taskbar Tweaker. It's dll would crash on these events.

I have downloaded the newest version of taskbar tweaker and now the problem is gone.

I was using 3.3.1 and the current version is 4.5.1

Comment: For reference, which version were/are you using?